# punctuation / uppercase (python)

Tags: python

I want to process a sentence using Python. First, I want to reverse the order of the words in the sentence. Then, I want to remove all words that do not begin with an uppercase letter. For example, `BaSe fOO ThE AttAcK` would become `attack the base`.

This is my code so far:

```
    a = input('code: ')
    b = a.split()
    b.reverse()
    g = ''
    for i in b:
        if i[0] == i[0].upper():
        g += i+' '
    print('says:',g.lower()[:-1])

#ex) BaSe fOO ThE AttAcK
     attack the base
#it all works but punctuation. it can't discern punctuation and uppercase/lowercase so, when I input !!! it makes !!!
#it has to make nothing when I input !!!
#Help me please.
```

This does not handle punctuation well - when I input `!!!` it outputs `!!!`, but I would like it to output nothing. I am also not sure it handles uppercase/lowercase well. How can I make my code work better?

Comment: What are you expecting? Your question seems unclear to me.

Answer (score 0):

You could remove the punctuations first before you do the other string processing tasks.

```
import string


a = input('code: ')

# Remove punctuations
translator = str.maketrans('', '', string.punctuation)
a = a.translate(translator)

b = a.split()
b.reverse()
g = ''
for i in b:
    if i[0] == i[0].upper():
        g += i + ' '
print('says:', g.lower()[:-1])
```

(And as general suggestions, use more sensible variable names, and please describe the question clearer next time.)